# Multiple Implementations passed in a list

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration, interface

I am New to Spring.I have this question which has been bothering me for a while now. Any help would be appreciated.

There is an Interface which calls a getter method.

```
interface MessageHandler{

    public List GetMessageCheckerList();

}
```

There is another Interface called MessageChecker which has multiple Implementations.
Say MessageChecker1, TestChecker, etc. (lets assume 2 for now )

Now how do i define this in the configuration xml file.

I actually have the bean created ,

here is the rest of the code

```
<bean id="checkerList" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="HL7Checker"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>


<bean id="HL7Checker" class="com.kahootz.messagereceiver.HL7CheckerImpl">
    <property name="messageExecutor" ref="Executor"/>
</bean>
```

Please Advice

When I actually run the program using a main method, I get the handle of one of the beans, The HL7Checker should be passed in a list to the Bean with ID=messageHandler. But when i print out the list. It is empty.

Without using spring and only using getter and setter methods , i am able "set" a list and retrieve it using Get.

Comment: What do you mean with "is not working"? Tell us what you expect and what you got instead.

Comment: Am I on the right path ? Please advice

Comment: I cannot tell if you are on the right path. The bean definitions look ok, so you should show us the code that accesses the beans. And please make the code as complete as possible. Best would be a program that one can compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Almost all of your names do not conform to the Java Naming Conventions. That makes it hard for others to understand your code.
2. The `<ref>` tag expects the name of an *object*, not the name of a *class*. So you need to define a `<bean id="testChecker" class="com.test.TestChecker" />` before you can reference it.
3. Don't use the package name `com.Test`. First, it should contain only lowercase letters. Second, you should be the owner of that name.